# Inequality relating expected value and tail probability

Tags: random-forest, probability-inequalities

I am currently working through [Scornet2015 - Consistency of Random Forests](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-43/issue-4/Consistency-of-random-forests/10.1214/15-AOS1321.full).

I'm having trouble understanding a specific inequality that is used in the proofs without further explanation. I am assuming it is something rather general and not immediately related to the topic at hand.

As far as I can see, the inequality boils down to the following (I'll quote the full statements below).

$$
\mathbb{E}[X] \leq \xi + u \mathbb{P}[X > \xi]
$$
where $u$ such that $X \leq u$.
Why is that? I've looked at various basic tools such as Markov or Chebyshev inequalities as well as inequalities for tail probabilities but none seems to apply here.

### First application

This considers (something like) the estimation error of a truncated estimate.

$$\begin{aligned}
& \left.\mathbb{E}\left[\sup _{\substack{f \in \mathcal{F}_n(\Theta) \\
\|f\|_{\infty} \leq \beta_n}} \mid \frac{1}{a_n} \sum_{i=1}^{a_n}\left[f\left(\mathbf{X}_i\right)-Y_{i, L}\right]^2-\mathbb{E}\left[f(\mathbf{X})-Y_L\right]^2\right]\right] \\
& \quad \leq \xi+2\left(\beta_n+L\right)^2 \mathbb{P}\left[\sup _{\substack{f \in \mathcal{F}_n(\Theta) \\
\|f\|_{\infty} \leq \beta_n}}\left|\frac{1}{a_n} \sum_{i=1}^{a_n}\left[f\left(\mathbf{X}_i\right)-Y_{i, L}\right]^2-\mathbb{E}\left[f(\mathbf{X})-Y_L\right]^2\right|>\xi\right]
\end{aligned}
$$

Earlier, it is established that

$$\sup _{\substack{f \in \mathcal{F}_n(\Theta) \\\|f\|_{\infty} \leq \beta_n}}\left|\frac{1}{a_n} \sum_{i \in \mathcal{I}_{n, \Theta}}\left[f\left(\mathbf{X}_i\right)-Y_{i, L}\right]^2-\mathbb{E}\left[f(\mathbf{X})-Y_L\right]^2\right| \leq 2\left(\beta_n+L\right)^2$$

### Second application

This considers the variation of the estimate $m$ in cells $A_{n}(\mathbf{X}, \Theta)$ of the random forest. The variation is defined as
$\Delta(m, A)=\sup _{\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}^{\prime} \in A}\left|m(\mathbf{x})-m\left(\mathbf{x}^{\prime}\right)\right|$ and thus upper-bounded by the supremum norm $\|f\|_{\infty}:=\sup _{x \in[0,1]}|f(x)|$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}\left[\Delta\left(m, A_n(\mathbf{X}, \Theta)\right)\right]^2 
& \leq \xi^2+4\|m\|_{\infty}^2 \mathbb{P}\left[\Delta\left(m, A_n(\mathbf{X}, \Theta)\right)>\xi\right]
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: In the applications you describe it is assumed that $X \lt u$, not that $\mathbb E[X] \lt u$. Deriving the inequality from there is straightforward

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Omega$ be the sample space and $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ a random variable. Assume $X < u$, i.e. $X(\omega) < u$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$.

Then

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X] &= \sum_{\omega \in \Omega} \mathbb{P}(\omega) X(\omega)  \\
&= \sum_{\substack{\omega \in \Omega \\ X(\omega) \leq \xi}} \mathbb{P}(\omega ) \underbrace{X(\omega)}_{\leq \xi} +  
\sum_{\substack{\omega \in \Omega \\ X(\omega) > \xi}}
\mathbb{P}(\omega) \underbrace{X(\omega)}_{\leq u} \\
& \leq \xi ~ \underbrace{ 
\mathbb{P}(X \leq \xi)
}_{\leq 1} + u ~ \mathbb{P}(X > \xi) \\
& \leq \xi + u ~\mathbb{P}(X > \xi)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: on a second thought, the first equality might not be completely correct, maybe you also have to sum over the range of $X$.